# Creating Multiarch Manifest

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to use Google Cloud Build to build multiarch images and a supporting manifest so I can run my containers on both amd64 and arm processors.  I can successfully build two images, but I'm unable to generate the multiarch manifest necessary... getting errors that manifests for the images I've just generated don't exist.

Here's the stage that fails:

`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'manifest'
  env:
  - 'DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled'
  args:
  - 'manifest'
  - 'create'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/village:$COMMIT_SHA'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/village:arm32v6'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/village:amd64'
  waitFor: ['amd64', 'arm']`

which produces the error:

`no such manifest: gcr.io/village/village:arm32v6
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker`

A previous step of my build results in: `Step #1 - "arm": Successfully tagged gcr.io/village/village:arm32v6`.

*Do I somehow need to push the individual images before generating the multiarch manifests?  Is it possible run continue running cloud-build commands after pushing images?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you have to `push` the dependencies before you can create the manifest.  Adding a step like below did the trick!

`- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  id: 'push-arm'
  args:
  - 'push'
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/village:arm32v6'
  waitFor: ['arm']`

I ended up documenting the final configs [here](https://medium.com/@bamnet/building-multiarch-docker-images-8a70002b3476) in case anyone else runs into this problem.